# Marketing Cloud - Reply Mail Management - Custom Setup Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

Our marketing cloud is setup to send from 3 different authenticated sub domains Eg:

- My.Business_name_1.com
- My.Business_name_2.com
- My.Business_name_3.com

We have a custom RMM setup so that if someone sends a email **directly** to john@My.Business_name_1.com it gets translated to john@Business_name_1.com by a custom data extension which is working fine however as we have 2 other sending domains we run into an issues as the custom RMM is only working on the first subdomain

Has anyone come across this issue before and found a solution around it?

Ideally we would like a catch all for the other 2 Eg: If any email is sent directly to something@My.Business_name_2.com or example@My.Business_name_3.com they are forwarded the same generic email address

So would expect the following to happen

- john@my.Business_name_1.com > john@Business_name_1.com via a Data Extension match
- *@My.Business_name_2.com > replies@Business_name_1.com
- *@My.Business_name_3.com > replies@Business_name_1.com

This issue has come about as Outlook is Auto saving our sending address for a person so when a customer creates an email they are using the Marketing cloud one rather than their correct one without knowing